# Using IOfficeAntiVirus interface in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Presently I am developing a small security application in Delphi. It is intended to be installed in Windows XP and higher OS-s and almost finished, but I'd like to implement the feature to scan MS Office files while opening. To that end, I'm planning to use IOfficeAntiVirus interface. I am trying to realize using the scan method of the interface based on the article by Serge Perevoznyk (http://www.delphi-central.com/MS_Office_AV_API.aspx).

The original example supposed to display a message box when a file is opened, however it does not, although I tried it on different versions of Windows and Office. I compared this solution with the information on MSDN. It seemed to be correct. I suppose there should be some additional settings in the Windows Registry which I missed to make. Can anyone give me some hint where shall I look for the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *use* [`IOfficeAntiVirus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you *implement* it.

You need to create a new ActiveX Library that contains a new ActiveX Control whose implementation class implements the `Scan()` method.  In the Control's registration code, you have to use [`ICatRegister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register your Control as using the `CATID_MSOfficeAntiVirus` category.  That way, Office/IE can find your ActiveX Control so it can instantiate it and call its `Scan()` implementation.  The second half of Serge's article shows you how to do that (Serge's example shows `Scan()` taking a `PChar` as input, but it actually takes a [`TMsoavinfo^`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  Don't pass `TMsoavinfo` using a `PChar`).

You then have to register the resulting DLL using Windows' command-line `regsvr32.exe` app.

If Office/IE is not calling your `Scan()` implementation, then you are likely not registering your ActiveX control correctly, such as if you are not taking 32bit/64bit and/or UAC issues into account.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information's sake if anyone is interested. Remy's answer is correct, however there is a small bug in the initialization section of the above mentioned example project.

Instead of

TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMsoTest, Class_MsoTest,
    'MsoTest', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);

The correct command is:

TMSOAVFactory.Create(ComServer, TMsoTest, Class_MsoTest,
    'MsoTest', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);